# Docker command line to show NodeID ContainerID and Hostname for all containers in swarm for a particular service

Tags: bash, docker

I'm looking for a single-line command to find all of `NodeID`, `ContainerID` and `Hostname` for all containers in a docker swarm that relate to service `srv-myservice`.

I've got as far as collecting the first two bits of info (`NodeID`, `ContainerID`) using `docker service ls`:

```
# SRV=srv-myservice; for f in $(docker service ps -q ${SRV} -f desired-state=running); do docker inspect --format 'NodeID: {{.NodeID}}, ContainerID: {{.Status.ContainerStatus.ContainerID}}' $f; done
NodeID: p49jhk0wliix4857u9pajbqlr, ContainerID: 41c1b5d4cfd899d96f0ca78e798636a6d4c7ea11002b69eee7bb0a78858c1c7e
```

And the last bit of info (`Hostname`) from `docker node ls`, along with `NodeID` to provide a link to the above:

```
# docker node ls --format 'NodeID: {{.ID}}, Hostname: {{.Hostname}}'
NodeID: p49jhk0wliix4857u9pajbqlr, Hostname: myserver-01
NodeID: 1cd89df9c89cb8477b3050ced, Hostname: myserver-02
```

I can then *manually* get the `Hostname` from the matching `NodeID` and put it together with the other info to get what I want:

```
Hostname: myserver-01, NodeID: p49jhk0wliix4857u9pajbqlr, ContainerID: 41c1b5d4cfd899d96f0ca78e798636a6d4c7ea11002b69eee7bb0a78858c1c7e
```

... but my abilities to merge these two steps into a single command-line statement are slightly lacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Awk for this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { map[$2]=$4;next } { print "Hostname: "map[$2]", "$0 } ' <(docker node ls --format 'NodeID: {{.ID}}, Hostname: {{.Hostname}}') <(for f in $(docker service ps -q ${SRV} -f desired-state=running); do docker inspect --format 'NodeID: {{.NodeID}}, ContainerID: {{.Status.ContainerStatus.ContainerID}}' $f; done)
```

Explantion:

```
 awk 'NR==FNR { 
                map[$2]=$4;                           # Process the first output (NR==FNR) - Set up an array map with the node id as the index and the host name as the value
                next ;                                # Skip to the next record
             } 
             { 
                print "Hostname: "map[$2]", "$0       # Process the second output, print the hostname from the map array along with the rest of the line
             } ' <(docker node ls --format 'NodeID: {{.ID}}, Hostname: {{.Hostname}}') <(for f in $(docker service ps -q ${SRV} -f desired-state=running); do docker inspect --format 'NodeID: {{.NodeID}}, ContainerID: {{.Status.ContainerStatus.ContainerID}}' $f; done)
```

Comment: Sounds promising, but I get a blank output

Comment: Apologies. I missed the second = in (NR==FNR) for the single line example. Try it now.

Comment: For future reference, for my own benefit, here is a slight modification which doesn't include the NodeID in the output (because the hostname is of more interest to me than the node id): `awk 'NR==FNR { map[$2]=$4; next } { print "host: "map[$2]", container: "$4"" } ' <(docker node ls --format 'NodeID: {{.ID}}, Hostname: {{.Hostname}}') <(for f in $(docker service ps -q srv-captain--${APP} -f desired-state=running); do docker inspect --format 'NodeID: {{.NodeID}}, ContainerID: {{.Status.ContainerStatus.ContainerID}}' $f; done)`